# Multiple Conqurrent Request Pause with axios-auth-refresh not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, jwt, refresh-token

I'm trying to implement, whenever request gets 401, axios will call refresh token end point and remaining request will pause during this process and with refreshed token, they will be called again. Because of this I'm using [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh/). First of all thanks Flyrell for this library.

My code is like this:
Instance creation:

```
    export const HTTP = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8088/api',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        params: {
            "connectionId": null
        }
        //headers: authHeader()
    });
```

Library configuraion:

```
    const refreshAuthLogic = async (failed) => {
    
        const tokenRefreshResponse = await HTTP.post('/auth/refresh', {
            refreshToken: authStore.refreshToken
        })
        console.log("failed", failed);
        if (tokenRefreshResponse?.data?.accessToken) {
            console.log("Refresh successful")
            authStore.accessToken = tokenRefreshResponse.data.accessToken
            authStore.refreshToken = tokenRefreshResponse.data.refreshToken
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    
        return Promise.reject();
    }
    
    // Instantiate the interceptor
    createAuthRefreshInterceptor(HTTP, refreshAuthLogic, {
        statusCodes: [401] // default: [ 401 ]
    });
    
    HTTP.interceptors.request.use(
        async (config) => {
            const date = new Date();
            console.log(`${date.toISOString()} - Calling URL: `, config.url);
            const token = await authStore.accessToken
            if (token && !config.url.includes("/auth/refresh")) {
                config.params["connectionId"] = authStore.connectionId
                config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;  // for Spring Boot back-end
            }
    
            return config
        },
        (error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
```

One of my components triggers conqurrent requests like this:

```
  try {

    const response1 = flowService.getFlows();
    const response2 = projectService.getProjectsTreeSelect();
    const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([response1, response2])
    flows.value = data1
    console.log("flows", flows.value)
    console.log("first request")

    //const response2 = projectService.getProjectsTreeSelect();
    projectsTree.value = data2
    console.log("projectsTree", projectsTree.value)
    console.log("second request")

    projects.value = projectsTree.value.map(p => ({
      projectName: p.label,
      projectCode: p.data
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error)
  }
```

I'm expectiing when a request fails with 401, second request will pause while refresh process, then promise will be resolved, but as I see in console every request is triggered. Then both get 401 and then one refresh is triggered. Is this the expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong. I'm also sharing console logs:

[Both failed and refresh success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZtG.png)

[Both failed and refresh also failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPR3l.png)

I'm expecting request interceptor created by library pause other requests.

Comment: The question is specific to low-profile lib, you may not get an answer because there aren't many users around. I guess the answer requires to be aware of its internals. At first sight, you don't use pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing which seems relevant

Comment: This setting is a poorly named one I think. Explanation from the documentation: In case your refresh logic does not make any calls, you should consider using the following flag when initializing the interceptor to pause the whole axios instance while the refreshing is pending. This prevents interceptor from running for each failed request.

{
    pauseInstanceWhileRefreshing: true, // default: false
}